# Is it possible to concatenate lists by including one list in another?

Tags: netlogo

I have two lists that will be created during runtime. I want to combine the lists that have been made so that the data can be accessed later on within the code , with the end goal of simplifying my code and improving my model efficiency. Can lists be concatenated by the inclusion of one within the other or is there another way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The usual way to concatenate lists is by using the [`sentence`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sentence) primitive. This will give you a new list made with the elements of your two original lists, like in Jen's answer.

Alternatively, you could use the [`list`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#list) primitive to build a list with your two original lists included as *sub*-lists.

The following example shows both methods:

```
to setup
  let list1 [ 1 2 3 ]
  let list2 [ 4 5 6 ]
  print sentence list1 list2 ; will print: [1 2 3 4 5 6]
  print list list1 list2 ; will print: [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]
end
```

Which one you should prefer depends, of course, on what you want to do with it...

Answer (score 0):

The sentence command can combine two lists without brackets left

```
to setup
  let mylist1 [1 2 3]
  let mylist2 [4 5 6]
  set mylist1 sentence mylist1 mylist2
  show mylist1
end
```

Comment: It's good that you are enthusiastic. However, this answer does not appear to add anything to the answer already provided.

Comment: Please [edit] to make more obvious the additional insight this provides in comparision to the other existing answer.